# How to reference a section without including its number to display only its level, e.g. "In this section, ..."?

Tags: cross-referencing

There are various possibilities to reference a section `\section{The First Section} \label{first}`:

- `\ref{first}` returns its number (e.g. "1").
- `\autoref{first}` returns its level and number (e.g. "section 1").
- `\nameref{first}` returns its name (I"The First Section").

But how do I get only the word "section" (or "chapter", or "item" – depending on the target's lever and type)?
That is, I'd like to get

> In this section, ...

from

```
\section{The First Section}
\label{first}
In this \typeref{first}, ... % whatever the command is called
```

and

> In this chapter, ...

from

```
\chapter{The First Section}
\label{first}
In this \typeref{first}, ...
```

---

This is the reason I cannot use `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrjura}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{contract}
        \Clause{title={First}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}\label{first}
        
        \Clause{title={Second}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}
        \ref{first}
    \end{contract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the command `\namecref` from the `cleveref` package.

Comment: Ah, in my case I had to drop cleveref because it's incompatible with some other package.

Comment: Are you sure that it’s incompatible? Usually, the problem with `cleveref` is that you have to load it *after* all other reference packages, including `hyperref` and `varioref`. If these packages are loaded in the right order, everything usually works out fine.

Comment: I've added an example with `scrjura` which doesn't work with `cleveref`

Answer (score 2):

When the hyperref package is loaded, the autoref-feature is available.

With the autoref-feature the type/level of reference is concluded from the name of the destination for hyperlinks that is stored in the cross-referencing-data.

You can copy that mechanism and in the copy eliminate those things that besides the name of the sectioning-level deliver spaces and `\the⟨counter⟩` of the referenced counter at the time of placing the cross-referencing-label.

(The mapping from the name of the destination to the phrase that occurs in the text is done by these `\...autorefname`- and `\...refname`-macros.)

In the example I added a mechanism using an `\if`-switch for having the first letter of the textual phrase as a capital letter if this is desired. This might yield unexpected effects in case `\sectioninglevelref` is used within moving arguments.

Apply `\nextsectioninglevelreffirstuppercase` only right before `\sectioninglevelref`. This way `\sectioninglevelref` has a fair chance to reset the switch before some `\autoref`-command might interfere.

```latex
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{scrjura}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\sectioninglevelref}{%
  \leavevmode
  \@ifstar{\HyRef@sectioninglevelref\@gobbletwo}{\HyRef@sectioninglevelref\hyper@@link}%
}
\newcommand*\HyRef@sectioninglevelref[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \Hy@safe@activestrue
  \expandafter\HyRef@sectioninglevelsetref\csname r@#2\endcsname{#2}{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*\HyRef@sectioninglevelsetref[3]{% link command, csname, refname
  \HyRef@ShowKeysRef{#2}%
  \ifcase 0\ifx#1\relax 1\fi\ifx#1\Hy@varioref@undefined 1\fi\relax
    \edef\HyRef@thisref{%
      \expandafter\@fourthoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
    }%
    \expandafter\HyRef@testsectioninglevelreftype\HyRef@thisref.\\%
    \Hy@safe@activesfalse
    #3{%
      \expandafter\@fifthoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
    }{%
      \expandafter\@fourthoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
    }{%
      \HyRef@currentHtag
      %%%%% \expandafter\@firstoffive#1\@empty\@empty\@empty
      \null
    }%
  \else
    \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
    \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
    \@latex@warning{%
      Reference `#2' on page \thepage\space undefined%
    }%
  \fi
  \ifnextsectioninglevelreffirstuppercase\global\nextsectioninglevelreffirstuppercasefalse\fi
}%
\@ifdefinable\HyRef@testsectioninglevelreftype{%
  \def\HyRef@testsectioninglevelreftype#1.#2\\{%
    \ltx@IfUndefined{#1autorefname}{%
      \ltx@IfUndefined{#1name}{%
        \HyRef@StripStar#1\\*\\\@nil{#1}%
        \ltx@IfUndefined{\HyRef@name autorefname}{%
        \ltx@IfUndefined{\HyRef@name name}{%
          \def\HyRef@currentHtag{}%
          \Hy@Warning{No autoref name for `#1'}%
        }{%
          \edef\HyRef@currentHtag{%
            \expandafter\noexpand\csname\HyRef@name name\endcsname
            %%%%%\noexpand~%
          }%
        }%
      }{%
        \edef\HyRef@currentHtag{%
          \expandafter\noexpand
          \csname\HyRef@name autorefname\endcsname
            %%%%%\noexpand~%
          }%
        }%
      }{%
        \edef\HyRef@currentHtag{%
          \expandafter\noexpand\csname#1name\endcsname
          %%%%%\noexpand~%
        }%
      }%
    }{%
      \edef\HyRef@currentHtag{%
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname#1autorefname\endcsname
        %%%%%\noexpand~%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newif\ifnextsectioninglevelreffirstuppercase
\global\nextsectioninglevelreffirstuppercasefalse
\newcommand\nextsectioninglevelreffirstuppercase{\global\nextsectioninglevelreffirstuppercasetrue}%
\makeatother

\makeatletter 
\newcommand\@AbsClauseautorefname{\ifnextsectioninglevelreffirstuppercase P\else p\fi aragraph}%
%\newcommand\@AbsClausename{\ifnextsectioninglevelreffirstuppercase P\else p\fi aragraph}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{contract}
        \Clause{title={First}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}\label{first}
        
        \Clause{title={Second}, preskip=0em, postskip=0em}

        \noindent \verb|\ref{first}|: \ref{first}

        \noindent \verb|\autoref{first}|: \autoref{first}

        \noindent \verb|\sectioninglevelref{first}|: \sectioninglevelref{first}

        \noindent \verb|\sectioninglevelref*{first}|: \sectioninglevelref*{first}

        \noindent \verb|\hyperref[first]{the first \sectioninglevelref*{first}}|:
        \hyperref[first]{the first \sectioninglevelref*{first}}
        
        \noindent 
        \verb|\nextsectioninglevelreffirstuppercase|\\
        \phantom{(6) }\verb|\hyperref[first]{the first \sectioninglevelref*{first}}|:
        \nextsectioninglevelreffirstuppercase  
        \hyperref[first]{the first \sectioninglevelref*{first}}

        \noindent \verb|\hyperref[first]{the first \sectioninglevelref*{first}}|:
        \hyperref[first]{the first \sectioninglevelref*{first}}

    \end{contract}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use zref to retrieve the counter:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{zref-counter,zref-user}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mynameref[1]{\csname \zref@extractdefault{#1}{counter}{XX}autorefname\endcsname}
\newcommand\enumiautorefname{Enumerate item}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chap}
\section{abc}\zlabel{sec}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \zlabel{item}
\end{enumerate}

\mynameref{sec}
\mynameref{item}
\end{document}
```

[image]